# Adding event to multiple buttons in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm listing my products like in the following image.

[image]

I want to add delete event to my delete buttons.

My product card html creator function looks like this.

```javascript
        getCardSummaryView: function(card) {
            var html = "";
            html += "</br>";
            html += "<div>";
            html += "<label>Product Name: " + card.Product.Name + "</label></br>";
            html += "<button id='deleteCard" + card.Product.Id + "'>Delete</button>";
            html += "</div>";

            return html;
        }

         array.forEach(response.products, function (item) {
           var view = this.getCardSummaryView(item);
            dom.byId("sideBar").innerHTML += view;

           var node = dom.byId("deleteCard" + item.Id);

           on(node, "click", function (e) {alert("something");})
        }
```

But if I add 3 product to panel, only last button click is populating, others doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you're getting all buttons before using on() using debugger or console.log(node). The error can be in the code you haven't posted. Try to make SSCCE jsfiddle example.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following line is problematic because on each iteration, you're rebuilding the DOM and destroying all the event listeners that you just added.

```
dom.byId("sideBar").innerHTML += view;
```

You can simply appendChild instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/rayotte/8uRXe/356/

```
require([
    "dojo/_base/array"
    , "dojo/dom"
    , "dojo/dom-construct"
    , "dojo/on"
    , "dojo/domReady!"
], function (
    array
    , dom
    , domConstruct
    , on
) {
    var getCardSummaryView = function (product) {
        var html = "";
        html += "<br/>";
        html += "<div>";
        html += "<label>Product Name: " + product.Name + "</label><br/>";
        html += "<button type='button' id='deleteCard" + product.Id + "'>Delete</button>";
        html += "</div>";
       return html;
    }

    var products = [
        {
            Id: 1
            , Name: 'Product 1'
        }    
        ,{
            Id: 2
            , Name: 'Product 2'
        }    
        ,{
            Id: 3
            , Name: 'Product 3'
        }    
    ]
    var sideBarNode = dom.byId("sideBar");
    array.forEach(products, function (product) {
        sideBarNode.appendChild(domConstruct.toDom(getCardSummaryView(product)));
        on(dom.byId("deleteCard" + product.Id), 'click', function(e){
            console.log('testing' + product.Id)
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: agreed, this is the cause of the problem. Vote up

Answer (score 0):

If i Where You i would do it this way because while you can see the buttons is created but that doesn't mean you can listen to them at that point so I will attach the buttons after the loop is done.

```
require(["dojo/_base/array","dijit/form/ValidationTextBox",
         "dijit/form/Button","dojo/dom","dojo/on","dojo/domReady!"], function(array,ValidationTextBox,Button,dom,on){

        var getCardSummaryView = function(card) {
            var html = "";
            html += "</br>";
            html += "<div>";
            html += "<label>Product Name: " + card.Product.Name + "</label></br>";
            html += "<button id='deleteCard" + card.Product.Id + "'>Delete</button>";
            html += "</div>";

            return html;
        }

     var objectvalue = {};
      var arrayvalue = new Array(); 

    objectvalue.Product = {};
    objectvalue.Product.Name = "hello1";            
    objectvalue.Product.Id = "ThisisWhy1";
    arrayvalue.push(objectvalue);
    var test = {};     
    test.Product = {};
    test.Product.Name = "hello2";            
    test.Product.Id = "ThisisWhy2";
    arrayvalue.push(test);


    var test2 = {};     
    test2.Product = {};
    test2.Product.Name = "hello3";            
    test2.Product.Id = "ThisisWhy3";
 arrayvalue.push(test2);


       array.forEach(arrayvalue, function (item) {

           var view = getCardSummaryView(item);
           dom.byId("sideBar").innerHTML += "----------------"
            dom.byId("sideBar").innerHTML += view;

           var node = dom.byId("deleteCard" + item.Product.Id);


        });      


              var myButton = new Button({
        label: "Click me!",
        onClick: function(){
         alert("1");
        }
    }, "deleteCard" + "ThisisWhy1");


              var myButton = new Button({
        label: "Click me!",
        onClick: function(){
       alert("2");
        }
    }, "deleteCard" + "ThisisWhy2");


              var myButton = new Button({
        label: "Click me!",
        onClick: function(){
       alert("3");
        }
    }, "deleteCard" + "ThisisWhy3");

});
```

ofcourse you can loop through the buttons when creating them but just to elaborate i created three instances
Click [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dernafees/8uRXe/347/) to see the working in jsfiddle.

Comment: How did you attached buttons(mayButton) to sitebar panels? No attachment in foreach loop. I can not add look like manually.

Comment: What i did was just creating the html first in the for loop and then attach the buttons separately, using dojo button. you can also look at that http://jsfiddle.net/8uRXe/353/. in this one i am looping to create the buttons.